# make fails during install of json-1.8.0 with unrecognized option '-arch' on OSX 10.8.4

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I am trying to get my ruby environment properly setup, but keep receiving errors when attempting to `bundle install` my test app.

I first get an error when trying to `bundle install`:

```
$ rails new app
// [...] 
run bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.9) 
Using activesupport (3.2.9) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.9) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.9) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.9) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activerecord (3.2.9) 
Using activeresource (3.2.9) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Installing json (1.8.0) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
gcc-4.6: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc-4.6: error: unrecognized option '-arch'
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Following the last line of the error message I attempt to `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` but get the following:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
gcc-4.6: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc-4.6: error: unrecognized option '-arch'
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I currently using the following versions of rvm, ruby + rails:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.9

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.22.1 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sounds like this can be caused by binary ruby, try:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p327 --disable-binary
```

Comment: I had the same issue but on a different gem. This would be true for any error where you see gcc-4.6: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc-4.6: error: unrecognized option '-arch'.

Comment: I have `gem`, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

delete gemfile.lock and run bundle

Comment: I know this answer does not explain itself, but it did work in my case!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rvm` installed, this should work:

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0-p247 --disable-binary
```

If you just updated OS X, you might want to try some other things first. See [thoughtbot's guide](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I decided to changing the default version of Ruby for 1.9.3p327.

Leaving the project folder and making the command:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-P327 --default
```

I do not know why this, for rvm modifies the version within the project, but after doing it gave no error when doing the 'bundle install'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set correct version your rvm. for example if your developed your application in ruby 1.9.3, you should set 
"*rvm use 1.9.3*". Then you can enter "*bundle install*" command. Maybe this will help you.

Thanks